# Assign more threads to VirtualBox guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, multi-threaded

I am running Windows 8.1 as host with Intel Core I7 4500U. I am trying to use OpenMP in Ubuntu using VirtualBox. However, even if I shared 2 CPUs, I still have one thread only. When I am running OpenMP for parallelism, it is only using one thread. Is there any way to add more threads to the Ubuntu guest OS, so that I can achieve parallelism in OpenMP?

Output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor` and how I call the compiler:

[image: blah]

Comment: How did you determine that you have only one thread inside the VM? Please provide the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor`.

Comment: How are you compiling your program?  E.g.
  [`g++ -fopenmp omp.cpp && ./a.out`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962363/openmp-in-qt-on-virtualbox-uses-only-one-thread)

Comment: If you open VirtualBox, click on the VM you want and then click settings it will open up a dialog where you can make changes to the VM. If you go to the System tab and then the processor tab, you can see how many cores are assigned to your VM, as well as add more cores. As Hydrax stated, what is the command you're using to compile the code?

Comment: @DanielB I have attached the output in the question. I cant embed the picture so it just a link

Comment: @Hydraxan14 I am using gcc testing.c -o testing.out -fopenmp

Comment: So you do have two virtual CPUs inside the VM. VirtualBox is not at fault.

Comment: @DrZoo As I said, I have allocated 2 cores to VM.

Comment: @DanielB So is it the problem of coding?

Comment: It would appear so. I’m not familiar with OpenMP, so I can’t help you with that, sorry. I suggest you ask on [so], with a full code example.